# fail2ban: ERROR No file(s) found for glob /usr/local/apache/logs*/*error.log

Tags: fail2ban

I don't get any solution for this problem.

On my jail.conf

```
[apache-404]
enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = apache-404
action   = csf-ip-deny[name=apache-404]
           sendmail-whois[name=Apache-404]
logpath  = /usr/local/apache/logs*/*error.log
maxretry = 3
```

On my system, file exists, /usr/local/apache/logs*/*error.log

Try /usr/local/apache/logs/error.log and other variants, but not work.

On all cases, get this message:

```
service fail2ban start
Iniciando fail2ban: ERROR  No file(s) found for glob /usr/local/apache/logs*/*error.log
ERROR  Failed during configuration: Have not found any log file for apache-404 jail
                      [FALLÓ]
```

Comment: Please check the permissions and the ownership of the log files under `/usr/local/apache/logs*/`. The user running fail2ban probably does not have to permission to read these files.

Comment: User it's root -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 44471 ene 18 16:47 /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log

Comment: You say the file is named "error_log" with underscore, not "error.log" with a dot. So you should change the your logpath entry to `/usr/local/apache/logs*/*error_log`

Comment: A lot of thanks. A despite for me.